# Filestream access denied via UNC / SQL

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I am having an issue with filestream and accessing the files. From the server itself I can access the files in the filestream folder when browsing direct on that computer. However when I try to browse the filestream UNC path on that server using localhost or from another computer it says incorrect function / don't have permission to view the share.

This was working fine, then Microsoft updates happened. We have since even upgraded to SQL 2017 and it is still not working. I have ensured that the owner of the folder is set to the same account as the service start up account. The permissions are set to allow me full control over that folder so I should be able to access it as well. Everything I have found online I have tried to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure: You did enable the filestream options in SQL Server Configuration Manages *and also* with sp_configure (set to 2)?

Comment: I know configuration manager is set to enable, where is sp_configure? I know inside SQL server properties it is set to full. The strange part is when I ran the query to see what level it was set to, it listed about 7-9 instances of the database and only one of them had access.

Comment: EXEC sp_configure 'filestream' I don't really follow what yo mean by seeing several instances of database, so if you want to elaborate (for instance share "that query").

Comment: What is the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: I have linked two images below that is the actual error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13jmE7hHBm7hZHG7MD7c-Ivcv9IzZ6r1p/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BSSGYBHBvmcKY02ByXidLZO9njQXijNF/view?usp=sharing